# Does a little bit of nuclear fusion happen in CRT monitors?

Tags: estimation, fusion

I recently was thinking about Farnsworth fusors, and thought "Jeez, that's crazy, how can inertial confinement fusion possibly be so easy?". So I decided to sanity check that Farnsworth fusors are plausible while walking to work. My thoughts went as follows:

1. I know that fusion happens in the sun at around $10^7$ kelvins, and the Boltzmann constant is $10^{-4}$ eV/K. So per-particle energies in the sun should be something like $10^3$ eV.
2. Hmm, this approximately makes sense. Chemistry happens at about $10^0$ eV, and fire (prototypical chemistry) is like $10^3$ kelvins, so it makes sense that the sun (being three or four orders of magnitude hotter than fire) should have per-particle energies that are three or four orders of magnitude higher.
3. I somehow always imagined that the gap between chemistry and nuclear physics was more than this? Farnsworth fusors are now totally plausible. If I accelerate my protons through just like a 10 kV gradient (about what's in a CRT monitor) then they accumulate stellar levels of kinetic energy.
4. ... wait a moment, why aren't CRT monitors Farnsworth fusors at some low rate from the occasional free proton going backwards through them? Are they? For that matter, if all it takes is like $10^3$ eV, do lightning bolts produce a little bit of incidental fusion? Is fusion just way easier than I thought, and happening at some vanishing rate in all sorts of places where high voltages occur? I always thought the gap between "chemistry" and "nuclear reactions" was enormous, but it's only like three or four orders of magnitude!

I asked a friend, and he suggested that maybe they are, but it's mostly just an issue of density. The sun is $10^2$ denser than water, which is $10^3$ denser than air, and yet the sun's power density is only about the same as the human body. So maybe there's a tiny bit of fusion happening in your CRT, but it's half a dozen orders of magnitude or so lower than you'd predict from the energies alone, due to the densities.

Another possible issue relates to the presumed lack of deuterium and tritium in your monitor, and also what the protons in your CRT typically end up ultimately colliding with — but I don't really understand what's actually required for fusion other than just "things hit each other really hard".

So, two questions:

1. Is this general line of reasoning about the relevant energies right?
2. Does a little bit of nuclear fusion happen in your CRT monitor/lightning/other places with high voltages, or is there essentially zero?

Comment: How many protons are accelerated by an electron gun?

Answer (score 2):

The log of the WKB tunneling probability $\ln P$ depends on an integral of the form $\int\sqrt{V-E}dx$. If you graph this versus E, it's extremely steep for E close to V, but not as steep when E is way below V. So at extreme sub-barrier energies, $\ln P$ will only go down moderately when you reduce the energy a little, but the thing is $\ln P$ is pretty big and negative, so even a small reduction hurts a lot.

So sub-barrier fusion is theoretically happening all the time, even in ordinary matter around us. However, the rate is not going to be detectable in the situation you describe, because (a) the number of positive ions is very small, and (b) pp fusion requires a weak interaction. This is why your typical hydrogen atom in the sun can go for billions of years without fusing.